# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS if I press Home Button in Video Player

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an application where I need to play a video. I used following code. There is a problem with Home button, if I press the Home button during video playing I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I even have no idea why it may happens. Please help.

```
    NSString * videoString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video.mp4" ofType:nil];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoString];
    MPMoviePlayerController * videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
    videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,768, 1024);  
    [videoPlayer play];
```

Comment: Might it have to do something, with the MPMoviePlayerController having some internal problems. I have also a problem with that controller. When i want to show a video and the server doesn't deliver any content it also crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I guess the videostream gets intrrupted and that causes the crash.

Answer (score 2):

In your application controller's applicationWillResignActive method, call [videoPlayer stop].